# Can't getContext of canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm facing a problem when i want to get the context of a canvas.
Here is the HTML code:

```
<canvas id="thecanvas" width="600" height="300"></canvas>
```

and the Javascript:

```
var canvaso = document.getElementById('thecanvas');
if (!canvaso) {
    alert('Error: Cannot find the canvas element!');
    return;
}
if (!canvaso.getContext) {
    alert('Error: Canvas context does not exist!');
    return;
}
```

The "canvaso" variable is correctly loaded, but it failed on "canvaso.getContext":

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'getContext'
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=canvas

Comment: see if your browser really is html5 compliant
http://www.smashcat.org/av/canvas_test/
http://html5test.com

Comment: I checked it, I use chrome and it is compliant.

Answer (score 3):

Your browser is not HTML5 compliant. A compliant browser would return `Object #<HTMLCanvasElement> has no method 'getContext'` (Although the getContext method would work)

[Works fine here](http://jsfiddle.net/fWa86/), are you sure you have a canvas by the id of thecanvas on the same page?

Here is a possibility: do you ever define a `div` with the id `thecanvas` anywhere in your document, most likely after the canvas? Duplicate IDS are semantically incorrect, and getElementById will return the last occurrence of that Id within the DOM.

Comment: My web browser is HTML5 compatible (I use chrome), and I had the canvas feature thorw other webpages, but not on this one.

Comment: You are right about the object. I get a HTMLDivElement instead of an HTMLCanvasElement, but I don't know why!

Comment: See edits, works fine in js fiddle. Here is a possibility: do you ever define a `div` with the id `thecanvas` anywhere in your document? Duplicate IDS are semantically incorrect, and `getElementById` will return the last occurrence of that Id.

Answer (score 3):

Try this (see Demo: http://jsbin.com/ijazum/1):

```
<body>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="300"></canvas>

  <script>
    function getStart() {
      var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

      if (!canvas) {
        alert('Error: Cannot find the canvas element!');
        return;
      }

      if (!canvas.getContext) {
        alert('Error: Canvas context does not exist!');
        return;
      }

      var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

      ctx.fillStyle = "#3d3";
      ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
    }

    getStart();
  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because you loaded your javascript as an external file in the `<head>` block of the page. This means that your javascript ran before the rest of the html elements like the `<canvas>` element were loaded. That's why your browser couldn't find any element with the given ID on the page - because the canvas element didn't exist at that point.

There are a few solutions to this:

1. Enter your javascript code into a `<script>` block anytime after you declare the `<canvas>` block.
2. Insert your javascript code into a function, then call that function as a reaction to any activity on the page, such as clicking a button or loading the page (using the `onload` attribute in the `<body>` tag).

A sample of the second solution has been shown below:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="myscript.js"> </script>
</head>
<body onload="test()">
  <canvas id="thecanvas" width="600" height="300"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

myscript.js:

```
function test() {
  var canvaso = document.getElementById('thecanvas');
  if (!canvaso) {
      alert('Error: Cannot find the canvas element!');
      return;
  }
  else if (!canvaso.getContext) {
      alert('Error: Canvas context does not exist!');
      return;
  }
  else {
      alert('Success!');
  }
}
```

Comment: So what does it mean, canvas context does not exist.... if it found it in the first if statement, why does it not exist?